# Emacs Not Running When I Try to Open a File (Windows)

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up

I'm trying to upgrade my Emacs distribution from 25 to 27 (aspell no longer works... I use Emacs for org mode and LaTeX).

When I select runemacs.exe, emacs starts just fine. It uses my init file. I can drag/drop files to open in this Emacs instance.

However, when I attempt to open any file associated with emacs by double clicking it (which starts an Emacs instance), I get the following message:

[image]

- How do I change the search directories?
- Alternatively, are there other fixes for this?

Comment: Which executable are you double–clicking on? Try `runemacs.exe`, if you haven’t already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm clicking on a file I want to open in emacs (such as any of my LaTeX files). Emacs will open if I run runemacs.exe. I get that error message when I'm directly choosing a file that I have associated with emacs. I think it's a PATH error, but I haven't figured it out... yet

Comment: Check that your files are associated with `runemacs.exe`, and not one of the other executables.

Comment: This sounds like you've associated the wrong `runemacs.exe` file. Barring that, the variable `load-path` contains all the paths being searched. Do you have a shortcut to the exe on your desktop? Does that work?